# Silverstripe routing issue to sub folders

Tags: routes, silverstripe

I have install silverstripe instance in a sub folder in an existing website.

`root/
   index.html
   sub-folder/
      silverstripe files`

I can navigate to the home page by hitting `mydomain.com/sub-folder` in the address bar. But I can not navigate in to the other pages, created in the silverstripe instance. ex: `mydomain.com/sub-folder/job-application` I think there is something I need to do inside a `routs` file.

Comment: does it help if you put `RewriteBase 'sub-folder/'` in you .htaccess?

Comment: @munomono: Thank you for commenting. Yes. I already added the `RewriteBase` entry in the .htaccess. I can navigate to home page. I Only cann't navigate to other pages.

Comment: have you tried accessing everything through the sub-folder/index.php ?  This index.php from SS is designed to do the normal url rewriting as an alternative

Comment: Have you specified the full path to the SilverStripe installation in your .htaccess? N.B. It should have done this itself if you installed it there.